# Does every positive, decreasing, real sequence whose series converges have a corresponding convex sequence greater than it whose series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

*Definition:* A real sequence $\ (x_n)_n\ $ is *convex* if $\ x_n - x_{n+1} \geq x_{n+1} - x_{n+2}\quad \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}. $

Suppose $\ (x_n)_n\ $ is a positive, decreasing sequence of real numbers such that $\ \displaystyle\sum x_n\ $ converges.

Proposition: There exists a convex sequence $\ (y_n)_n,\ $ such that:

1. $\ y_n\geq x_n\quad \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ and
2. $\ \displaystyle \sum_n y_n\ $ converges.

I suspect there is some counter-example, and I think my best attempt to find one is that maybe there is an increasing subsequence $\ (A_n)_n\ $ of $\ \mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ x_n:= \frac{1}{A_k}\ $ for all $\ n\ $ with $\ A_{k-1} < n \leq A_k,\ $ and then maybe the convexity of $\ (y_n)_n\ $ sort of forces $\ y_n \approx \frac{1}{n}\ ?$ But I'm not sure if this is true or how to prove this.

Edit: I have spent more time thinking about this problem without further progress towards a solution. Therefore I have added a bounty of $+50$.

Comment: I think I can prove that there is $y_n \ge x_n$ decreasing and quasi-convex st $\sum y_n < \infty$ where quasi-convex means that $\sum (n+1)|\Delta^2 y_n| < \infty$  where as usual $\Delta^2 a_n=y_n-2a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$, so when $a_n$ is convex bounded, hence decreasing to some limit $a$, we have that $\sum_{n=0}^N (n+1)|\Delta^2 y_n| =a_0-(N+1)(a_{N+1}-a_{N+2})-a_{N+1} \to a_0 - a$ as $(N+1)(a_{N+1}-a_{N+2}) \to 0$ because $a_{N+1}-a_{N+2}$ is decreasing with convergent sum, hence the name quasi-convex; not sure though if that helps as I kind of believe too that indeed the answer is no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. The idea is to consider a finitary version of the problem, which can be handled via LP.

Let $M = 2\sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i$.

**Lemma**: for every $n \geq 0$, there exists a sequence $Y_n = (y_1, \cdots, y_n)$ that satisfies

- $y_i \geq x_i$.
- $y_i$ is convex, meaning $y_i + y_{i + 2} \geq 2y_{i + 1}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n -2$.
- $\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 2} y_i \leq M$.

**Proof**: We can pose this as a standard LP problem. Let $y_i' = y_i - x_i$. Then the LP is

- Constraint 1: $y_i' \geq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.
- Constraint 2: $y_i' - 2y'_{i + 1} + y'_{i + 2} \geq - x_{i} + 2x_{i + 1} - x_{i + 2}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n - 2$.
- Objective: minimize $\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i'.$

By the fundamental lemma for LPs, this has the same solution as its dual LP, which is posed as follows.

- Constraint 1: $z_i \geq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n - 2$.
- Constraint 2: $z_i - 2z_{i + 1} + z_{i + 2} \leq 1$ for all $-1 \leq i \leq n - 2$, where we assume $z_{-1} = z_0 = z_{n - 1} = z_n = 0$.
- Objective: maximize $\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 2} (-x_{i} + 2x_{i + 1} - x_{i + 2})z_i.$

We can arrange the objective as
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} (x_i - x_{i + 1})(z_{i - 1} - z_{i}).$$
Let $d_i = z_{i - 1} - z_i$. Then we have $d_0 = d_n = 0$ and $d_{i - 1} \leq d_i + 1$. The important observation is that $\boxed{d_i \leq i}$. To justify this claim, we divide it into two cases.

**Case 1**: $i \leq n / 2$. Then we have
$$z_{2i - 1} = -\sum_{j = 1}^{2i - 1} d_j.$$
We can split the sum into two parts. For $j < i$, we have $d_j \geq -j$ since $d_i \geq d_{i - 1} - 1$ and $d_0 = 0$. For $j \geq i$ we have $d_j \geq d_i - (j - i)$ for the same reason. So we conclude that
$$z_{2i - 1} \leq - \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} (-j + d_i - j).$$
However, $z_{2i - 1} \geq 0$, so we conclude that $d_i \leq i$.

**Case 2**: $i > n / 2$. In this case, we have $d_i \leq d_n + (n - i) =n - i \leq i$.

So we have shown our observation. The objective of the dual LP is at most (btw, this is where the assumption that $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing is used)
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} (x_i - x_{i + 1}) i \leq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i.$$
So the objective of the original LP is also at most this value, and we conclude the existence of $Y_n$ by finding the optimal solution to the original LP $\{{y_i'}^*\}$ and setting $y_i = {y_i'}^* + x_i$.

Pad the sequence $Y_n$ with zeros to make it an infinite sequence $Y_n = (y_1, \cdots, y_n, 0, 0,\cdots) \subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. The rest of the argument is compactness.

Note that the entries of $Y_n$ are bounded by $M$. By diagonalization or Tychonoff's theorem, we can find a subcollection $\{Y_{n_i}\}_i$ of $\{Y_n\}_n$ that converges pointwise(i.e. in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$) to a sequence $Y_\infty$. Now $Y_{\infty}$ is convex and upper bounds $x_i$ by pointwise convergence(in more fancy terms, these properties are ``open" in the topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$), and lies in $L^1(\mathbb{N})$ by Fatou's lemma.

Comment: +1. Very nice application: the only thing I'd feel compulsory is to explicitly state that "LP" means "Linear Programming".

Comment: I don't fully understand this answer because I have no experience with Linear Programming. However, I wonder if your answer (which like I say, I do not understand) implies that each $y_i$ can be written as the sum of members of $x_i,$ each one used at most twice. So for example, If $(x_n) = (4,4,3,1,3/4,1/50,1/100,1/10000,\ldots),$ then a convex $6-$tuple that uses the sum of members of $x_i,$ each one used at most twice, could be $(4+4,3+3,4,1+1,3/4,1/50,1/100,1/10000,\ldots).$ Or does your linear programming solution not necessarily imply $y_n$ are sums of $x_n$?

Comment: Basically I was wondering if the thing I was alluding to in my previous comment, that   "$y_i$ (with the properties in the original question) can be written as the sum of members of $x_i,$ each one used at most twice", was true.

Comment: No I don't think my solution gives something like this... though I admit my solution is a bit strange, and maybe a direct constructive solution can be found.

Comment: @abacaba fair enough. I have posted (the finite version of) my question in my previous comment as a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865127/using-two-copies-of-a-decreasing-k-tuple-can-you-form-a-convex-decreasing-k

Comment: I am probably mistaken. But don't we need to mention that one of the problems dual or primal is at least feasible to conclude the existence of an optimal solution?

Comment: I think the primal is feasible by taking $y_i' = C i^2$ for sufficiently large $C > 0$.