# Does every positive real sequence whose series converges to $a$ have a "straight line" convex subsequence that also converges to $a?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, linear-programming

This question is possibly related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4596465/does-every-positive-decreasing-real-sequence-whose-series-converges-have-a-cor) and it's answer.

Suppose $a_n>0\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}\ $ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = a.$

Does there exist a subsequence $(a_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the sequence defined by:

$b_1 = a_{k_1}=a_1;\ $  and for each $n\in\mathbb{N},\ b_i = a_{k_n} + \frac{i-k_n}{k_{n+1}-k_n}\left( a_{k_{n+1}} - a_{k_n} \right)\ $ for all $i$ with $k_n < i \leq k_{n+1},$

has the properties that $(b_n)$ is convex and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = a?$

Note that without the restriction $a_n >0,\ $ the sequence $(a_n)= 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{25},\ldots$ would be a counter-example.

There are many variations of this problem, but out of all of them, this one stuck.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: Why is $(a_n)= 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{25},\ldots$ a counterexample?

Comment: We have: $a_1 = 1,\ a_2 = 0,\ a_3 = 0,\ a_4 = 0,\ a_5 = 0,\ a_6 = 0,\ a_7 = 0,\ a_8 = 0,\ a_9=\frac{1}{4},a_{10}=\frac{1}{9},a_{11}=\frac{1}{16},a_{12}=\frac{1}{25},\ldots.\ $ From the properties in the question, we must have $b_1 = a_1 = 1.\ $ Now, either $a_{k_2}= a_2\ $ or $a_{k_2}= a_3$ and so on. If $a_{k_2}= a_2\ $ then due to convexity of $(b_n),$ we must have $b_2=0,\ b_3=0,\ b_4=0$ etc, and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n =1\neq a=1.64.$ If $a_{k_2}= a_3,\ $ then we must have $b_2=\frac{1}{2}\ $ and $b_3 = 0,\ b_4 = 0,\ b_5 = 0,\ldots $ and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n=1.5 \neq a=1.64.$...

Comment: ...If $a_{k_2}= a_4,\ $ then we must have $b_2=\frac{2}{3}\ $ and $b_3 = \frac{1}{3},\ b_4 = 0,\ b_5 = 0,\ b_6 = 0,\ldots $ and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n=2 > a=1.64.$ Similar reasoning if $a_{k_2}= a_5 $ or $a_6,$ and so on... So basically there is no choice of $a_{k_2}$ that gives $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = a.$